# MySQL query - average amount of lines per order, on a monthly basis

Tags: mysql

I have a table which shows previous orders.
Each item bought is added as a seperate row in the table, see dump below.

My aim is to show the average amount of lines per order on a monthly basis. 
To get an average amount of lines, I need to divide the amount of items bought by the amount of orders placed.

My query currently gives me the monthly totals, and `line_count` returns the correct number of items bought, but I can't seem to return the amount of orders placed (which in the dump below should give 13).  I have tried adding various subqueries, but I'm not sure how to go about this.  Any ideas?

```
SELECT 
date, 
COUNT(orderno) AS line_count 
FROM `orders` 
AND 
date BETWEEN '2010-01-21' AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY month(date), year(date) 
ORDER BY date
```

Here is the table schema (simplified for clarity)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orderno` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=22904 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `orders`
--

INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `orderno`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'rad10000', '2010-01-21'),
(2, 'rad10000', '2010-01-21'),
(3, 'rad10001', '2010-01-21'),
(4, 'rad10001', '2010-01-21'),
(5, 'rad10002', '2010-01-21'),
(6, 'rad10003', '2010-01-21'),
(8, 'rad10003', '2010-01-21'),
(9, 'rad10003', '2010-01-21'),
(10, 'rad10004', '2010-01-22'),
(11, 'rad10004', '2010-01-22'),
(12, 'rad10005', '2010-01-22'),
(13, 'rad10005', '2010-01-22'),
(14, 'rad10006', '2010-01-22'),
(15, 'rad10007', '2010-01-22'),
(16, 'rad10008', '2010-01-22'),
(17, 'rad10009', '2010-01-22'),
(18, 'rad10010', '2010-01-22'),
(19, 'rad10011', '2010-01-22'),
(20, 'rad10012', '2010-01-22');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I see...

```
 SELECT YEAR(date)
      , MONTH(date) 
      , COUNT(*) line_count 
      , COUNT(DISTINCT orderno) orders_placed
   FROM orders
  WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-01-21' AND CURDATE() 
  GROUP 
     BY YEAR(date)
      , MONTH(date)  
  ORDER  
     BY date;
```